# Why do we expect that Brownian motion remains in the ball $B(0,\delta )$ provides $T\ll \delta ^2$?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)$ a Brownian standard motion and $$\mathcal B(0,\delta )=\{\varphi \in \mathcal C_0[0,T]\mid \|\varphi \|_\infty \leq \delta \},$$
where $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$ is the set of continuous function on $f:[0,T]\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(0)=0$. It's written in my lecture that if $T\ll \delta ^2$ we expect that Brownian motion remains in $\mathcal B(0,\delta )$ but I don't really understand the reason. I know that $B_t\sim \mathcal N(0,t)$, so the standard deviation of $B_t$ is $\sqrt t$, but I never really understand what it really mean. Does it mean that $B_T\in [-\sqrt{T},\sqrt{T}]$ and thus if $T\ll \delta ^2$, then $[-\sqrt T,\sqrt T]\subset \mathcal B(0,\delta )$ ? But I don't see any result that says that if $\sigma $ is the standart deviation of a r.v. $Y$ then $\mu-\sigma \leq Y\leq \mu+\sigma $ where $\mu$ is the means. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hopefully improve intuition:

- We are dealing with a random variable, hence we *never* know *exact* what the outcome will be (it's actually a measurable function, per se). The standard deviation is the square root of the expected quadratic variance (or simply, variance). The **increments** of a Brownian motion are normally distributed to be precise, but remember that it is continuous.

Maybe your professor wants to tell you about ["stopping times"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) without going too much into detail.

But sure, you can use a stop time T (stopping the Brownian motion at a desired point) to guarantee that the process is inside the ball you defined, i.e. stopping it when the supremum hits $\delta$. Then $B_T$ (the stopped process) is a continuous function, with $B_0 = 0$, inside the ball.

(The Brownian motion can be dangerous, e.g. having infinite local variation, everywhere. )